# Google Maps in Modal not centered

Tags: google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a Google Map in a modal. But it the center is not what I want.

I use following script:

```
<script>
      function initMap() {

        var lattp = <?php echo json_encode($lattp);?>;
        var lngtp = <?php echo json_encode($lngtp);?>;
        var zoomtp = <?php echo json_encode($zoomtp);?>;
        var tp = {lat: JSON.parse(lattp), lng: JSON.parse(lngtp)};  

        var latrest = <?php echo json_encode($latrest);?>;
        var lngrest = <?php echo json_encode($lngrest);?>;
        var rest = {lat: JSON.parse(latrest), lng: JSON.parse(lngrest)};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: JSON.parse(zoomtp),
          center: tp
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: rest,
          map: map
        });}
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(tp);
    });

    </script>
```

The result is not what I want. You can check it: https://www.checkjevoeding.be/uitstap/tp_rest_dishes.php?id=9

Just click on "Aanduiding parkplan"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the `map` and `tp` out of the `initMap()` method as it is not accessible outside the method.

```
<script>
  var map, tp;
  function initMap() {
    var lattp = <?php echo json_encode($lattp);?>;
    var lngtp = <?php echo json_encode($lngtp);?>;
    var zoomtp = <?php echo json_encode($zoomtp);?>;
    tp = {lat: JSON.parse(lattp), lng: JSON.parse(lngtp)};  

    var latrest = <?php echo json_encode($latrest);?>;
    var lngrest = <?php echo json_encode($lngrest);?>;
    var rest = {lat: JSON.parse(latrest), lng: JSON.parse(lngrest)};

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: JSON.parse(zoomtp),
      center: tp
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: rest,
      map: map
    });
  }
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
     map.setCenter(tp);
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was my problem, didn't know how that vars!